# Spring Session Redis fails to deserialize with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:

Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException:

Failed to deserialize object type; 
  nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.user.model.CurrentUser
```

I have two typical Spring Boot applications that share a Redis instance for session state.  The above error happens immediately upon trying to log in to my application.

I'm not quite sure what's going on here - both applications use the same libraries and versions for the applicable User models and Spring dependencies.  For what it's worth `CurrentUser` extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, which itself is `Serializable`.

I've rebooted my Redis instance thinking something just got funky, but that was not the case.  I'd show what I've tried already, but it's mostly been making sure my artifacts were built correctly and restarting application and Redis servers, with a little bit of toying around with `Serializable`.

Why am I seeing this?

Comment: Are all the members of CurrentUser also Serializable?

Comment: Few questions: Is the Redis configuration (more specifically the serialization part) the same in both apps? If I understood correctly `CurrentUser` is located in external library shared between both apps? Are you using Boot DevTools? Sample that reproduces the problem or at the very least relevant parts of configuration for both apps would be useful to have.

Comment: Snickers - yep.

Vedran - what information would be helpful to you?

Comment: @BrandonV were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue :/

Comment: @varunkr I did solve the issue, but unfortunately, I can't recall what did it.  Sorry.

Comment: @varunkr same issue. If you had written the solution, I would have been thanking you 3 years later. lol.

Comment: @varunkr @ Aekansh Kansal I too facing the same issue...Have u guys been able to solve this. Is so please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Most Probably you will receive this error when the sender server is not the same as the receiving server (separate servers)

The issue is from the **ValueSerializer**

To avoid this issue, use **Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer** as the value Serializer for both sender and receiver

```
    @Bean
    protected RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
      final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
      template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
      .........
      return template;
    }
```

this way the serialization process will be json based instead of class based

Answer (score 1):

The exception says 'Cannot deserialize'
It looks like you stored something in Redis, that now cannot be deserialized.
May be you changed the serialVersionUID meanwhile ?

I saw you restarted Redis, but may be the entry is persisted and survived the reboot ?

Comment: I will give that a check.  It's entirely possible that AWS Elasticache is allowing data to survive the reboot.

The object did change, but I was hoping the reboot would flush the store.

Comment: No luck.  Re-created the cluster and same issue.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: check if you used different codec/serializiation compared to what you use while de-serialiation .

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing the data to the redis just typecast it in Object class and when you are fetching it back from redis just fetch it as Object .Then typecast it into whatever POJO class you have. It worked in my case.
When storing->

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("<YOUR-key>", "<YOUR-field>",(Object) empList);
```

When fetching->

```
Object employeeFromCache=operation.get("<YOUR-key>", "<YOUR-field>");
        employees=(List<Employee>)employeeFromCache;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same. Storing the data into Redis in One service and fetching it from another service. I faced the same issue(Deserialization).
I made common Library containing the 'Serializable' Class. Used the same library for both Services. It worked for me.
Let me know if there are any issues with this implementation.
Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Default spring boot configuration for `valueSerializer` in Redis is `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`.

So when you change your object that cached before in Redis, you have to remove it from Redis too.

Ultimately you need to remove your Redis key values on application startup like this:

```
@Component
public class RemoveCachesOnStartup {
  private final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate;

  @PostConstruct
  public void doAfterStartup() {
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    int count = 0;
    Set<Object> keys = redisTemplate.keys("*");
    if (keys != null) {
      for (Object key : keys) {
        if (key.toString().startsWith(CACHE_PREFIX)) {
          redisTemplate.delete(key);
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    log.info("total {} data redis records have executed", count);
  }
```